# Verilog syntax error in module declaration

Tags: module, syntax-error, verilog

I am receiving a syntax error for the declaration of my second module, where I have indicated in the comments. I am using an online Verilog simulator so it does not tell me what kind of error. I'm really confused because I followed the same set up as the first module and I am not getting an error there. Does it have to do with reusing the variables? I tried changing them and it didn't seem to work.

```
    module MagnitudeComparator4Bit(input [3:0] a, input [3:0] b, output eq, output lt, output gt); 
assign eq = a==b;
assign lt = a < b;
assign gt = a > b;
 endmodule

module 8bitMagCompare(input [7:0] a, input [7:0] b, output EQ, output LT, output GT); //SYNTAX ERROR
wire w1, w2, w3, w4;
MagnitudeComparator4Bit MagComp1(a[7:4], b[7:4], w1, LT, GT);
MagnitudeComparator4Bit MagComp2(a[3:0], b[3:0], w2, w3, w4);
assign EQ = w1 && w2;
endmodule

module MagCompareTB;
reg a, b;
wire EQ, LT, GT;

8bitMagCompare testcompare(a, b, EQ, LT, GT);

initial begin
$monitor("%d A=%a, B=%b, EQ=%b, LT=%b, GT=%b", $time, a, b, EQ, LT, GT);
    #10 a = 00000000;
        b = 00000000;
    #10 a = 10000000;
        b = 00000000;
    #10 a = 00000000;
        b = 10000000;
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

It it so obvious that you miss it: the second module name start with a number!

But I also am not happy about your code for the second module. You should use all the result of the second (LS) instance if the first (MS) instance reports equal.

Try testing it with e.g. 00010000 and 00010001.